# How do you use pyenv with Apache and Django?

Tags: django, apache, pyenv

I'm trying to use pyenv to create a virtual environment to use with Django on Apache (it works great for development outside of Apache). I'm a bit miffed though on what user to set up the environments and run with (attempting to `su` commands with `www-data` fails as it's "not currently available")...should I use `root` (OK because it just would own everything, not run whatever), make another user, etc.

I haven't been able to test, but I'm assuming that I should add the shims path to `PATH` in `/etc/apache2/envvars` then let each site set `PYENV_VERSION` in it's Apache `.conf` as appropriate.

Comment: It depends how you are setting up your apache, whether it is a virtualhost (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) or a standalone website on apache?

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a standalone site. Could you respond to this case please @vishen ?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to run a command as another user use: `sudo -u <user> command`. In order to use `su` that user must be configured in `/etc/passwd` to have a shell. You can always just do `sudo -u www-data bash` instead.

With respect to your question about pyenv. You should install pyenv somewhere where the apache user has permissions. You will need to create a directory since, www-data is unlikely to have a home directory.

Comment: Yes, but how do you get apache and mod_wsgi in my case, to use that pyenv install directory?